# Is it possible to do LIST operations on the value of a HASH?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, nosql

I am still new to Redis and wondering if it would be possible to have a `HASH` of `LIST`.

Then I could do for example `LPOP HASH myKey` where the hash set holds each list's key and the lists contains data that I want to manipulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis does not provide nested data structures, therefore a List of Hashes isn't possible. A Redis List can only contain strings, but what you could do is store the Hashes' key names in a List and do `HGET` after popping.